# PlayerPrefs.Save() вызывается при перезагрузке?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Знаю что люди делают `PlayerPrefs.Save()` дабы избежать сбоев, но при перезагрузке телефона вызветься ли оно само? т.к. оно вызываеться при `OnApplicationExit()`, считаеться ли перезагрузка и выключения? И что если в телефоне сядет баратея, вызветься ли `OnApplicationExit(`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, смотрим [документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html) внимательно:

> In cases when the game crashes or otherwise prematuraly exits, you might want to write the PlayerPrefs at sensible 'checkpoints' in your game.

Из чего можно сделать вывод, что как минимум крэш приложения - ситуация, когда сохранение `PlayerPrefs` не произойдет автоматически. Так же напипасано, про другие "внештаные" ситуации выключения приложения.

Думаю, что в случае с разрядом батареии или перезагрузке телефона нельзя точно сказать или узнать как поведет себя Unity, потому что это зависит от того, вызываются ли те или иные нативные ивенты в операционной системе того или иного смартфона. Unity в свою очередь подвязывается на те ивенты, которые только может, но если система в определенный случай не вызывает никакого события, то Unity с этим сделать уже ничего не может.

И так как подобные случаи предугадать для всех мобильных ОС достаточно сложно, в качестве хорошей практики, Unity предлагает сохранять данные в PlayerPrefs "логическими пачками" и затем принудительно делать `Save()`. Я бы не стал полагаться на то, что `Save()` должен вызваться автоматически (а на практике может и не вызваться) и принудительно сохранял данные.

Comment: а может ли какой-то метод 100% вызваться при перезагрузке?

Comment: Возможно, сработает потеря фокуса?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский т.е. информация под вопросом? Сейчас проверю.

Answer (score 0):

> а может ли какой-то метод 100% вызваться при перезагрузке?

Перезагрузка телефона бывает обычной и хард-ресетом. В случае с хард-ресетом ты никак это не отловишь в любом случае. А вот обычная должна послать ивент `OnApplicationQuit()` в юнити и он сохранит все автоматически. (кстате, вручную сейв вызывать там НЕ нужно)

> т.к. оно вызываеться при OnApplicationExit()

А выключать апликуху тоже можно по-разному. Вот если выключать стандартным способом -- `OnApplicationQuit()` сработает.

Но если через настройки вырубить - совсем не факт. Я не проверял, но вангую что **НЕ** сработает.

> И что если в телефоне сядет баратея, вызветься ли OnApplicationExit()?

А кто тебе гарантирует что у телефона батарея живая? Ну то есть если батарея там изношенная, то телефон без генерации всяких ивентов просто отключится т.к. будет думать что батарея еще есть, а на практике вольтаж упадет ниже нужной отметки.

---

Лично мое мнение:

- **Лучше сохранять настройки вручную СРАЗУ после изменения** , а не надеятся на то что это за тебя сделает юнити по какому-либо ивенту.
- Или во время LoadingScreen (если это будет занимать много времени, то юзер все равно это не почувствует)

Но, возможно, я просто параноик :)

Comment: я так и делаю, только зависает на 0.5 - 1 секунду.

Comment: Это долго. Какое общее количество переменных приблизительно хранится там? И какого рода переменные? Такое чувство, что ты там хранишь что-то лишнее что нужно хранить в другом месте

Comment: я храню около 30 переменных, ну это самое важное, все переменные int, 2-3 строки размеров 10-30 символов. Они все в JSON'e